# Different --compilation_mode for external dependencies

Tags: bazel

Is it possible to mix targets build in a different compilation mode? I want to compile external dependencies, which are rarely changed in `-c opt`, but I want build my internal code in `dbg` or `fastbuild` mode

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is stick `-O2` in `copts` of external dependencies or use `--per_file_copts` in a `.bazelrc` file.

On some platforms, `--compilation_mode` has global implications on position-independence and linking behavior. So, it wouldn't necessarily make sense to switch `--compilation_mode` for part of a build.

Comment: For build using automagically resolved cc_toolchain and perhaps if I do not worry about building the tree with various toolchains, then just `copts` could be an option. Otherwise I'd go with [`features`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.features) to configure packages / targets accordingly and allow for toolchain specific meaning.